# Not able to subset dataframe inside df.apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, let's call it trim_df, indexed by user_id like so:

```
           d_timestamp_dt                flagged
user_id                                         
1234567890     2015-04-30                  False
0987654321     2015-04-30                  False
```

I'm trying to create an "accum" variable using df.apply(), like so:

```
df['new_col'] = df.apply( lambda row: my_func( row, time_period1 ), axis=1 )
```

And here is how my_func is defined...comments show what executes when I run apply():

```
def my_func( row, time_period ):
    print type( row ) # <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

    user_id         = row['user_id'] # 123456789
    row_time        = row['d_timestamp_dt'] # 2015-04-16 23:05:00
    user_rows       = trim_df.loc[user_id]
    print type( user_rows ) # <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> WHY??? shouldn't it be a DataFrame?

    user_rows_of_interest = user_rows[((user_rows['flagged'] == True) &
                                      ((row_time - user_rows['d_timestamp_dt']) > time_period0) &
                                      ((row_time - user_rows['d_timestamp_dt']) < time_period))] 
    print type( user_rows_of_interest ) # <class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'> ...expecting this to be a DataFrame 
    return len( user_rows_of_interest ) # breaks, because Timestamp doesn't have len()
```

What's REALLY confusing me is, when I try to step through the function (not using apply) with just one row, I get the DataFrames that I expect i.e., not the Series and then Timestamp. Really appreciate any insight into what's going on!

Comment: time_period1 = ?  Also, your function relies on the global time_period0.

Comment: time_period1 is defined as datetime.timedelta( days=1 ). Also, I left out something really important - the dataframe df to which I'm applying this function is different from trim_df i.e., it does have user_id columns and is indexed by row_id, not user_id.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set the user_id to the index value of the row.  The lambda expressio passes each row of the DataFrame as a Series, and the DataFrame doesn't have 'user_id' as a column (it is the index column).

```
user_id = row.index
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that trim_df.loc[user_id] is the culprit...it's returning a Series. I'm not quite sure why, perhaps because user_id (although the index) is not unique? trim_df.loc[trim_df.index == user_id] seems to be working.